# Carry over arguments to new URL

Tags: php, html, url, href

I am working with some anchor tags in HTML where i need to carry over some arguments from the first url to the second url

```
<a href="newpage.html">My Link</a>
```

My current URL is - `oldpage.html?arg=value`

But the "My Link" redirects to -

```
newpage.html
```

and not

```
newpage.html?arg=value
```

How do i carry over the value of `arg` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just copy a known variable over, it's as simple as

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"newpage.html?arg=" . urlencode($_GET["arg"]) . "\">My Link</a>" ?>
```

and then `oldpage.html?arg=value` would produce a link to `newpage.html?arg=value`.

However, if you want to pass over the entire query string, you can achieve this with the `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` variable.

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"newpage.html?" . urlencode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) . "\">My Link</a>" ?>
```

This will propagate the entire query string to the new page. So if you accessed the current page with `oldpage.html?arg=value&color=green`, the link would point to `newpage.html?arg=value&color=green`.

Alternatively you could use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), allowing you to add extra parameters or modify the existing query string as you see fit.

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"newpage.html?" . http_build_query($_GET + array("foo" => "bar")) . "\">My Link</a>" ?>
```

Using this, navigating to the current page as `oldpage.html?arg=value` would produce a link to `newpage.html?arg=value&foo=bar`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="newpage.html?arg=<?php echo $_GET['arg']; ?>">My Link</a>
```

Comment: This solution worked better for me. @sargant's urlencode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) was turning my ampersands into special character code %s.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do this:

```
<a href="newpage.html?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>">My Link</a>
```

But that is only if your server allows you to use SERVER variables.