# Passing Queries on multiple across multiple pages

Tags: wordpress, url

When I generate a lead I get the values passed on via the URL Query which is the following:

?fname=[value]&lname=[value]&email=[value]

I’d like to know how I can carry this query over to the next page as well? (so the URL is passed over two pages instead of just the one).

So it would flow like this:

LeadPageExample.com -> Lead entered details -> LeadPageExample.com/Upsell?fname=Alex&lname=Smith&email=asmith@email.com -> Lead clicks on cancel or add to cart (I want fname=Alex&lname=Smith&email=asmith@email.com to be passed on again) -> LeadPageExample.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=312&fname=Alex&lname=Smith&email=asmith@email.com

Essentially I want the fname=Alex&lname=Smith&email=asmith@email.com query to be re-attached to the next link and passed on twice in this scenario.

To illustrate:

LeadPageExample.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=312&fname=Alex&lname=Smith&email=asmith@email.com

Any ideas? Is it possible? If so, how?

To be even more specific, I ONLY want this to happen on specific webpages on my wordpress site.

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: You need to $_GET the variables from URL and then dynamically add them in any link that he/she might click. If it's just in the checkout workflow should be even more staightforward.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any resources for me to look at how to do this? I'm not a developer but competent to putting things together. Would this work by carrying the variables over from the previous page?

Comment: There is no better place than stackoverflow! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639220/carry-over-arguments-to-new-url/20639629  Have a look on how they do it. Preferably write it cleanly in a function and then invoke it in the links you need. If you need more help update your question with your code and I ll try to answer!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.